# How to make header background 100% height?

Tags: css, wordpress

We are using [this Wordpress design](http://pexetothemes.com/demos/story_wp/home-default/) and it looks good, but what we want to achieve is to make the image 100% of the screen height: i.e. so that initially all they can see is the 'slider' before they can then scroll down to see the other content. An example of how this works can be [found here](http://themes.webcreations907.com/ninezeroseven/option-one/).

I would have thought this was possible with CSS, but despite setting several containers to have a height of 100% it doesn't seem to be working. What trick I am missing here? Does it relate to background-size perhaps?

Comment: what about background-size attribute? you can give `auto 100%;` values, but it's CSS3, so IE8 won't recognize it

Comment: Hi @Cheshire thanks for the suggestion. My issue is that I cannot work out which container to place this on. I would have thought setting the container height to 100% and then doing a background-size:cover would have worked, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only [care about modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can use viewport units:

```
.your-selector {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

...but you haven't shared any code. This is a broad question with a lot of possible answers.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of code - I wasn't really sure which part to share as having played around with the various containers that contain the 'slider' I was none the wiser.